# Java Overriding Error

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I got the following error:

> name clash: add(E) in AVLTree<E> and add(E) in BinaryTree have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

and I have no idea what the problem is.

```
public class BinaryTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E> {
    public class AVLTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinaryTree {
```

the add method in both classes is written as:

```
public void add(E toInsert) {
```

I hope I provided everything i needed. I'm stumped by this so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: please format code properly - cut and paste from your IDE then click "{}" to have it formatted as code

Comment: I think you mean "public static class AVLTree ..." that is, you should add "static" to the definition of AVLTree. This has nothing to do with the name-clash problem, though

Answer (score 1):

Looks like AVLTree is an inner class, so the parameterized type `E` is visible. Try this:

```
public class BinaryTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E> {
    public class AVLTree extends BinaryTree<E> {
```

I must say it's a little weird having an inner class extend its containing class. Not implausible; I've just never seen it done before.

Comment: when i tried that i got: 

cannot find symbol
symbol  : class E
location: class AVLTree

i dont understand what you mean by the inner class extending its containing class though

Comment: It turns out i just needed to modify my AVLTree class to:

public class AVLTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinaryTree<E> {

thanks for the help though!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the original question just had misleading formatting. To have an inner class extend its containing class is [pretty dangerous](http://ideone.com/Ol2A8).